# using ifelse to remove outliers

Tags: r, if-statement, outliers

I would like to remove outliers based on the function below, that is xhigh values.

```
   low <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)-5*(mad(x)) 
   high <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)+5*(mad(x))   
   out <- if_else(x > high, NA_real_,ifelse(x < low, NA_real_, x)) 
   out }
```

values of x>high were replaced with NA, but x<low were retained in the dataset.
How should I modify the function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `dput(x)` to show the data that you encountered this problem with.

Comment: Did you check my below answer here? If it did work you can accept this answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
low <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE) - 5*(mad(x)) 
high <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE) + 5*(mad(x))
x[x > high | x < low] <- NA
x
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine for me, but I don't understand why you mixed `if_else` and `ifelse`:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- c(rnorm(85, 50, 3), rnorm(15, 50, 15))
summary(x)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   28.11   47.78   50.41   50.23   52.19   70.88 
low <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)-5*(mad(x)) 
high <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)+5*(mad(x))   
out <- if_else(x > high, NA_real_,ifelse(x < low, NA_real_, x)) 
# Note this would be simpler: out <- ifelse(x > high | x < low, NA_real_, x) 
out[x > high]
# [1] NA NA
out[x < low]
# [1] NA NA
```